# How to retrieve nodes under two collections from Firestore?

Tags: node.js, database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have this structure:

```
- collection(A) // there is two collections in the Firestore in the top.
                   // But I only wrote one the collection because it gets longer
     - doc(918409234)
              -collection(B)
                   - doc(918409234)
                             object is stored here
                   - doc(213123133)
                             object is stored here
                   - doc(332222212)
                             object is stored here
                   - doc(029299292)
                             object is stored here
                   - doc(434352342)
                             object is stored here
     - doc(341234123)
              -collection(B)
                   - doc(918409234)
                   - doc(213123133)
                   - doc(332222212)
                   - doc(029299292)
                   - doc(434352342)
     - doc(341234123)
              -collection(B)
                   - doc(918409234)
                   - doc(213123133)
                   - doc(332222212)
                   - doc(029299292)
                   - doc(434352342)
```

So I want to retrieve nodes under collection B, but it does not seem to be working. What is wrong with my code?

**When to post:**

```
 function send() {
     let path = db.collection(A).doc(randomnumber).
     return path.collection(B).doc(randomnumber).set(object);
 }
```

**When to fetch:**

```
 function fetch() {
     return db.collection(A).get().then(value => {
        value.forEach((doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        }));
        return value;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error found' + err)
        return err;
    })
 }

let snapshot = await firestore.fetch();
console.log('Snapshot: ' + snapshot); // prints [Object, Object]
snapshot.forEach(child => { 
    let query = child.data(); 
    console.log('Each data: ' + query.B); // not printed in the console
});
```

But I cannot get the first documents. So I cannot go to the next step to fetch the next collection(in this case collection B). The fetch method is invoked but only printed as [Object, Object]. What is wrong with this code? I expect to fetch three nodes in the example above. Am I doing wrong? I want to fetch all docs which are assigned with a random number

**UPDATE**

So the problem is solved. You cannot access nested collections(hopefully as of now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to retrieve nodes under two collections from Firestore?

There is no way to achieve this. Firestore queries are shallow, they only get items from the collection that the query is run against. There is no way to get documents from a top-level collection and other collections **or subcollections** in a single query. Firestore doesn't support queries across different collections in one step. A single query may only use properties of documents in a single collection.

> So I want to retrieve nodes under collection B

If you want to get all documents within your B collection, you need to know that document id (918409234) in order to create a correct reference and query the that subcollection accordingly. Without knowing it, you cannot get those documents. To solve this, you should store that random document id into a variable and use it in your reference or set the document id as a known id, let's say a user id.

Comment: I understand but when you store an object using .doc(), this makes an random id, so you can add objects using .doc(), but for that, you can fetch all documents right doing this way? But why is it not allowed in this case?

Comment: "when you store an object using .doc(), this makes an random id", that's correct. If you want to have another id, just pass that id as an argument to the `doc('new_id')`. You say: "you can fetch all documents right doing this way?", yes you can but only from a single collection at a time. "But why is it not allowed in this case?" This is how Firestore works.

Comment: Okay I understood. So that issue is solved. Thank you very much, but another issue I had is that all docs in the collection A are even not fetchable right now. I wondered if it is because of my programatic mistake, not something that Firestore does? Appreciate your help.

Comment: @RyoheiArai You're welcome. Most likely is because something is wrong in your code. If you encounter new problems, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you. Cheers!